# Send 3 byte-data to OpenGL GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I am working on a little Voxed-based game. I don't plan to create a Minecraft copy, but it's not the point here.

Using C++ OpenGL and VBO, I can't successfully send "non standards" type to my GLSL Shader.
Assuming a struct composed of 3 uint8_t attributes, I am trying to send an array of this struct to my glsl. But I can't get the correct value.

The most accurate thing I found was : [WebGL - How to pass unsigned byte vertex attribute colour values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201826/webgl-how-to-pass-unsigned-byte-vertex-attribute-colour-values)

But it doesn't really answer the question I have.

Here is some code to help understanding what I am trying to do. I don't even know if there is any solution to achieve it ...

**My structure**

```
struct Color
{
    uint8_t r, g, b;
    // Getter and setter etc...
};
```

**How I Bind it to the VBO**

```
//_colors contains an array of Color
//_colors.array = new Color[SIZE];

glBind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _colors.buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
              sizeof(Color) * _colors.size, 
              &(_colors.array[0]), 
              GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

**How I try to send them to the GPU**

```
glBind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _colors.buffer);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLint)1, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

I store the value in a vec3 in my shader, but I have no doubt this isn't the right way to do. I know I'm wrong somewhere, But I don't understand what I can do (and As I say, maybe it's even impossible).

Thanks for your help / advices !

Comment: What are the *expected* and the *read* values? `ivec3` might be more appropriate. Also, are you sure that no padding is introduced into your struct?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Why? He's using `glVertexAttribPointer`. That can't feed `ivec3`s.

Comment: Yeah definitely check to see if you have any padding at the end of the struct.

Comment: So I should add an "unused" uint8_t attribute to my struct, to fit a 4byte struct ?

I was also thinking of sending an unsigned int to glsl and "packing" my value into it (first byte for R, second for G, third for B)

Comment: @NicolBolas Waaat. Wat. `4.3.4 - Vertex shader inputs can be single- or double-precision floating-point scalars, vectors, and matrices, or signed- and unsigned-integer scalars and vectors` Why can't one use `VertexAttribPointer` for that?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: That's not a GLSL matter; [it's an OpenGL matter](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_format). `glVertexAttribPointer` can only feed vertex shader inputs that are floating-point values. Just as `glVertexAttribIPointer` can only feed signed or unsigned vertex shader inputs. Just as `glVertexAttribLPointer` can only feed double-precision inputs.

Comment: @NicolBolas Damn, it's on the boundaries of GL and GLSL, obviously, and I found it hard to find. Thanks a lot for that link! So I presume OP should use `glVertexAttribIPointer`, then.

Comment: Is the size of struct Color guaranteed to be 3, and the stride of struct Color[] guaranteed to be 0? AFAIK the compiler is allowed to pad the struct (for alignment, etc.). You are hardcoding stride to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, today I've learned about [other versions of `glVertexAttrib`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_format), and I can answer you now ;)

If you want to pass integer vertex attributes to shader as-is, you have (obviously) to use `glVertexAttrib`**`I`**`Pointer`. If you want to receive floating point input (e.g. `vec3`), take a look at the linked page and the conversions applied.

Comment: Thanks you all for your answer, now it's working exactly as I expected, I think i'll keep your link @BartekBanachewicz, a lots of very useful informations there !

Comment: @Xleek I just wanted to remind you that you can mark my question as *accepted*, just below its score :)