# Pack/Unpack 4 bytes into Integer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compression

As the title says, I have been trying to pack 4 full 0-255 bytes into 1 integer in c# using BitShifting. I'm trying to Compress some data, currently using 40 bytes of data. But really in theory I only need 12 bytes, but to do so I need to compress all my data into 3 Integers.

Currently my data is:

```
        float3 pos; // Position Relative to Object
        float4 color; // RGB is Compressed into X, Y is MatID, Z and W are unused
        float3 normal; // A simple Normal -1 to 1 range
```

But in theory i can compress to:

```
        int pos; // X, Y, Z, MatID - These are never > 200 nor negative
        int color; // R, G, B, Unused Fourth Byte
        int normal; // X, Y, Z, [0, 255] = [-1, 1] with 128 being 0, Unused Fourth Byte Should be plenty accurate for my needs
```

So my question is how would i go about doing this? Im reasonably new to Bit Shifting and havent managed to get much working.

Comment: I don’t see any “bit shifting” code. What is the question?

Comment: "I have been trying to pack 4 full 0-255 bytes into 1 integer in c# using BitShifting" -> post code attempt and what is the concrete problem :)

Comment: `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` using this layout show us how you want this to work

Comment: Why would you want to convert a float to int? You may lose precision data.

Comment: Also, is there any real reason to do this. Unity has superior ways to to stream data to the cpu using data oriented design, packing things into an int isn't really going to solve much unless you have a memory issue

Comment: @user2864740 I'm trying to figure out how to make said Bit Shifting, I'm still learning it.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I don't really have anything solid to show since I have barely even gotten anything to work, I don't fully understand Bitshifting in general.

Comment: @kiner_shah In my case i don't need remotely close to the accuracy of a float, I just need 0-255 values for most of these to get pretty much an identical result.

Comment: @TheGeneral This is basically a point cloud, I use this data on the CPU and GPU, and i need Millions of them. So packing the data to fewer bytes should reduce memory usage.
Since I'm still just learning how to directly work with Binary/Bitshifting I'm not sure how to use your layout as an example. Isn't that only 8 bytes each byte being 4 bits? I need 12 bytes?

Comment: @NuclearWolf all fair enough. However, you need to describe how you want it packed you have 32 bits to work with, show how you want this to work, then someone can show you how to pack and unpack them in code.

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm not really looking for a Specific format, I was hoping to find a general method to convert 4 bytes to 1 int and then reverse it, I don't need anything too specialized, or at least I don't think I do? An int to my knowledge is comprised of 4 bytes, so it should be possible to store 4 unique bytes inside an int?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators

Comment: This sounds a little bit like a case of overoptimising things ... Are you sure you want to go that road and not rather use a few bytes more? Like do you think this encoding and decoding operation (and debugging and maintaining it) is more efficient than using a little bit more of memory / bandwidth? And why store 4 different bytes in an in at all? Why not leave them as individual bytes or a `byte[]` ?

Comment: @derHugo Well, I'm not looking to add any more data. The issue now is this uses 40MB of VRam per "Chunk" of data 100 of those chunks is 4 GB of data. This optimization can bring it all the way down to 1.2GB which is much more reasonable. I'm also actively passing this data between the GPU and CPU, I imagine passing 4GB is much slower than 1.2GB So I possibly get free performance boosts from it as well.

Comment: @NuclearWolf fair enough but have in mind that your CPU will also need to encode/decode these 1.2 GB into the original data formats .. is this really faster then? Have you tested if you gain anything by doing this actually? And still: Why go the complex way of parsing this in an from `int` in specific? Why not use a raw `byte[]` / memory stream?

Comment: @derHugo That's a very good point, a Byte[] array would be ideal, the issue is I'm passing this data to the GPU, the GPU to my knowledge has no "Byte" forcing me to use it something else like an Int to store the data anyway. The CPU never properly reads the data it's mainly the GPU doing the work.

Comment: @NuclearWolf Never done GPU coding so far but I'm pretty confident that any device in a PC understands the concept of a `byte` / `byte[]` or `byte*` better then a `c#`-specific type `int` which basically in the memory just is a `byte[4]` ... which is the case lso for `float` ... so my point is .. why use a complex bitshift way to compose one of these types out of raw bytes instead of simply use the raw bytes themselves? You could as well simply create a `byte[12]` and fill the elements one by one

Comment: @derHugo You cant actually create a byte on the GPU. I have no idea why but GLSL and HLSL and any shader language I have worked with so far don't acknowledge bytes. Doing "byte test = 0;" will not compile, nor will byte[] or anything else with bytes. closest thing it accepts is an Int.

Comment: aaah so you are talking about a shader.... Have you tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201826/webgl-how-to-pass-unsigned-byte-vertex-attribute-colour-values) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958859/send-3-byte-data-to-opengl-glsl) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238977/discussion-between-nuclearwolf-and-derhugo).

Comment: `Im using Unity, so i dont think i can access OpenGL directly like that.` -> what do you think [GLSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language) stands for? ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right, you need to store 4 values in 4 bytes (one value per byte) and then use individual values by performing bit shift operations.

You can do it like this:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        uint pos = 0x4a5b6c7d;
        // x is first byte, y is second byte, z is third byte, matId is fourth byte
        uint x = (pos & 0xff);
        uint y = (pos & 0xff00) >> 8;
        uint z = (pos & 0xff0000) >> 16;
        uint matId = (pos & (0xff << 24)) >> 24;
        Console.WriteLine(x + " " + y + " " + z + " " + matId);
        Console.WriteLine((0x7d) + " " + (0x6c) + " " + (0x5b) + " " + (0x4a));
    }
}
```

`x` will be equal to result of `0x4a5b6c7d & 0x000000ff` = `0x7d`

`y` will be equal to result of `0x4a5b6c7d & 0x0000ff00` right shifted by 8 bits = `0x6c`

Similar for `z` and `matId`.

#### Edit

For packing, you need to use `|` operator:

- Left shift fourth value by 24, say `a`
- Left shift third value by 16, say `b`
- Left shift second value by 8, say `c`
- Nothing for fourth value, say `d`
- Do a binary OR of all 4 and store it in an `int`: `int packed = a | b | c | d`

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    static void Unpack(uint p)
    {
        uint pos = p;
        // x is first byte, y is second byte, z is third byte, matId is fourth byte
        uint x = (pos & 0xff);
        uint y = (pos & 0xff00) >> 8;
        uint z = (pos & 0xff0000) >> 16;
        uint matId = (pos & (0xff << 24)) >> 24;
        Console.WriteLine(x + " " + y + " " + z + " " + matId);
    }
    
    static uint Pack(int x, int y, int z, int matId)
    {
        uint newx = x, newy = y, newz = z, newMaxId = matId;
        uint pos2 = (newMaxId << 24) | (newz << 16) | (newy << 8) | newx;
        Console.WriteLine(pos2);
        return pos2;
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        uint packedInt = Pack(10, 20, 30, 40);
        Unpack(packedInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about packing the data into pos?
THis data is generated on the fly, so I need to create Pos from 4 bytes.

Comment: @NuclearWolf, edited. Please check.

Comment: Thank you! Also, thanks for the step-by-step breakdown of it, helps a lot with understanding what it's doing!

Comment: Unpack(Pack(0, 0, 0, 255)) returns int4(0, 0, 0, -1)
Unpack(Pack(0, 0, 0, 200)) return int4(0, 0, 0, -56)
Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: Using unsigned Integers fixed it!

Comment: @NuclearWolf, yes signed int will return -1 for 0xff. I edited my answer and replaced int with uint.